# Are international students (Tier 4 visa) in UK allowed to travel a domestic flight without a passport?

Tags: air-travel, uk, customs-and-immigration, passports, domestic-travel

I have to travel from Edinburgh to Belfast, and then Belfast back to London.
But before that trip, I just applied for the Schengen Visa so my passport would be at the embassy, and I don't think I can get it back on time before my flights.

I am an international student from Thailand, on Tier4 visa. Am I allow to travel on that domestic route without my passport (I will fly with Flybe and Ryan air)
? Can I use my Biometric Residence Permit card instead?

Comment: BRP will be fine too.

Answer (score 4):

The UK has no restrictions on internal travel. You might require photo ID to board the flight, but that does not need to be a passport. Check with the airline for exactly what ID is acceptable.

Comment: Photo ID is up to the operator. BA never asks me for any ID at all. Eastern Airways and Flybe are more strict.

Comment: I say it depends on the mood of the person checking IDs at the counter. It would suck if they didn't let you board because of a lack of ID.

Comment: Airlines usually have a list of acceptable IDs.

Answer (score 1):

[For UK travel, RyanAir states](https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview/Travel-documentation/Are-driving-licenses-accepted-as-a-travel-document-on-Ryanair-flights):

> Any photo ID which matches  the passenger name in the booking.

[FlyBe has a long list, a few of which may apply to you](http://www.flybe.com/checkin/id-requirements.htm):

> - Valid Government-issued identity card

(Presumably this would include a BRP)

> - NUS card (National Union of Students)
> - University/college ID card